# Abstract Controller in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I've started using Spring Boot few weeks ago and I still can't get my head around the notion of "AbstractController".

```
public abstract class AbstractController {

    protected static final String CUSTOMER_SESSION_ID = "auth";
    protected static final String SHOOPY_CART_ID = "SHOOPY_CART";

    protected static final String REFERER_HEADER = "Referer";

    @Autowired
    protected CatalogService catalogService;

    @Autowired
    protected TotalAmountCalculator amountCalculator;

    @Autowired
    protected CustomerRepository customerRepo;

    @Autowired
    protected CartRepository cartRepository;


    //Insert necessary data to the header tag
    public void populateHeaderData(Model model, Cart activeCart) {
        HeaderDTOBuilder.HeaderDTO headerDTO = new HeaderDTOBuilder().
                withAmountCalculator(amountCalculator)
                .withActiveCart(activeCart)
                .withCategories(catalogService.getCategories()).build();
        model.addAttribute("headerDTO", headerDTO);
    }


    public void populateHeaderData(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cart activeCart = getCartFrom(request);
        if(activeCart == null){
            activeCart = new Cart();
        }
        populateHeaderData(model, activeCart);
    }

}
```

I would love to understand what's the difference between a Controller and an AbstractController.

Comment: If you have some common functionality between controllers

Comment: Thank you @Deadpool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `Abstract` to the name of the class is a simple way to designate that this class is `abstract` (declared as `public abstract class` in your case). This means that this class was developed to incorporate some common functionality which will be reused by several child classes. Also there are such classes in JDK itself like `java.util.AbstractList`

You can find more information about concept of abstract classes here https://www.journaldev.com/1582/abstract-class-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You would only create an abstract controller when you have or plan to have several controller classes with shared logic or instance variables.